# Doctrine: Hijack a delete operation and make record invalid instead

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

In order to avoid the [Slowly Changing Dimension problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Slowly_changing_dimension) (in short: I want to keep my order data even if a user gets deleted from the system), I thought about hijacking the `delete` event and instead setting an `invalid` flag on the record.

- I know of the `softdeletable` filter from StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle but I'm unsure if this will cascade to child objects.
- Is this a common/good practice/idea and do this with the following lifecycle callback?:

/

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove
 */

public function makeInvalid() {
    $this->enddate = new \DateTime(); // set the end of validity property to now
    cascadeToRelatedObjects(); // i.e. make sure all 'child' objects also change validity
    somehowContinueTheOperation(); // i.e. do not cause an Error of sorts
}
```

- or should I, rather, change the functionality of the delete button on the form and assign an update function to it which does the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, using the `softdeleteable` from `DoctrineExtensions` is the way to go. It even cascades fine if you set the `cascade={"remove"}` option correctly on the property of your owning object (generally speaking, the one with OneToMany).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need to set `onDelete="CASCADE"`, as this is a function executed by the database, which is unaware of the requirement to soft-delete, so it won't soft-delete any children.

The easiest way for me to get this extension, was to installing `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` with the command `composer require StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` and configuring it in `config.yml`, you can use it as described below. Soft-deleting an instance of `Device` will then also soft-delete its dependent `Parts`.

For restoring them you'd probably have to write a function or something.

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * ...
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */

class Device {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Part", mappedBy="device", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $parts;
}
```